# object is closed vba excel ADODB

Tags: excel, vba, adodb, recordset

I get Operation is not allowed when the object is closed error.

Why I do get this error?
[Error location][2]

There is nothing wrong with the connection.

I can do SQL queries on the same cmd connection and have no problems with them.

Only this query messes me up.

I usually don't use Set search path or table short names, but just incase got
into very detail this time.

When I run the same query in PostgreSQL I get the result:

[postgres output for the same SQL query][1]

I have been digging around google for hours and I can't find any answers.
Does it have to do something with drivers?
How do I know what driver I use for excel?
What driver I should use?
How I change driver?

[References I use][3]

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4nLe.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4uJo.png
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytrlk.png

CODE

```
Public Function getDBArray(cmd, strSQL)
    Dim recordID As Long, recordAmount As Long, totalFields As Integer, fieldID As Integer
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL '' << this is the strSQL i copy pasted directly to pgadmin and it worked
    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    totalFields = getTableAmount(rs.Fields)
    recordAmount = getTableAmount(rs) ' << error in this function
    recordID = 0
```

Comment: As per your 2nd screen shot the error actually occurs in function `getTableAmount()`, you should add that to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was not suppose to used SET SEARCH PATH